# Yii Conditional Validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

I have a question about Yii validation. I have a dropdown whose options are Y and N. If the user select Y the user must explain why he chose Y hence a textArea box will become required.

My code for the rule looks at follows.

`array('explain', 'check', 'trigger'=>'med_effects'),`

Check is my function used for validation

```
public function check($attribute, $params)
    {
        if($this->$params['trigger'] == 0 && $this->$attribute == '') {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Explain the effects of the medicine');
        }
    }
```

The value for `$this->$params['trigger']` does not change. I'm assuming because the saved value was 0(Y) and does not change even if the user choose N. How am I supposed to determine which option the user chose when he sumbits the form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property inside your model:

```
public $isDropDownChecked;
```

In your view, create a dropdown wired to new property created.

And return a array of rules inside the method rules() like this:

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules[] = array(); 

   if ($this->isDropDownChecked == 'Y')
        $rules[] = array('explain', 'check', 'trigger'=>'med_effects');    


   return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I have no clue on how this would help me because this is not what I'm asking.

Comment: When I had this situation, I've inserted the dropdown value in the model, and in my rules method checked if ($this->property == 'Y') $rules[] = array(.... ) //validate reason. It works, isn't?

Comment: So you passed in a variable when you first created the instance of the model? `new Model($something)`?

Comment: Just create a property inside of it.  public $isDropDownChecked; Create the dropdown wired to the model property and use it inside rules() method.

Comment: Ok thanks. I worked. I just did it in the opposite way to suit what I intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may also help someone on Yii1,
say you have three fields with a lookup of [Yes|NO], and you want atleast one field to be selected as Yes

Here is the solution
on your model add

```
public $arv_refill;
public $prep_refilled;
public $prep_initiate;
```

on your rules add

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
   array('arv_refill,prep_refilled,prep_initiate','arvPrepInitiateValidation'),
    );
 }
```

arvPrepInitiateValidation being a function

```
public function arvPrepInitiateValidation($attribute_name,$params)
    {
        
        if($this->arv_refill != 1 && $this->prep_refilled != 1 && $this->prep_initiate != 1){
            $msg = "arv_refill, prep_refilled or prep_initiate field must have one field as Yes";
            $this->addError('arv_refill',$msg);
            $this->addError('prep_refilled',$msg);
            $this->addError('prep_initiate',$msg);
        }
    }
```